# What does the percentage value in get() method of List class in eclipse means

Tags: java, eclipse

I was looking in to this Java code and suddenly I found a percentage value displayed against the intellisense in eclipse. Any idea what does the 9% in the image refers to ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the *likeliness* that this method ts the one you want to invoke here by the context of the current code position.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Though I tried hard at guessing this, I wonder if I would have ever come to this conclusion.